# Please help me solve the m1 iOS simulator error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Spec.
Hardware: M1 Pro
IDE: Xcode 14

After the project is created, the console error message below occurs during runtime without any other settings.

Have you ever dealt with an error like this?

> objc[6742]: Class SBFCARendererImageRepresentation is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardFoundation.framework/SpringBoardFoundation (0x1067895a0)

and

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PaperBoardUI.framework/PaperBoardUI (0x104ffd930). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

Comment: sorry.
IDE : Xcode 16 -> 14

Comment: Try another simulator. Or wipe your simulator.

Comment: This is annoying. I used the "erase all contents and settings" and that didn't get rid of it.

Comment: I found [this thread](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/691361) useful in explaining why this might have popped up in debug area. I started to get the message when I had to define my `Firebase.configure()` function inside a `UIApplicationDelegate` object instead of doing it inside the default initializer. I hope you can glean some meaning off of that pertaining to your own project.

Comment: I've tried looking up the two files in question on the Mac, but Apple makes searching for stuff on their computers another whole massively complex problem.  Apple pretty much sucks in a LOT of ways, it's what happens to monopolies, and it's only going to get worse.  This should be a massive source of embarrassment to those at Apple supposedly catering to devs.  Stand up at conferences and shout this stuff out.  Embarrass them.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, this is just log spam and can be ignored.

Comment: This is not really an answer.

Comment: @livingtech Yes it is. It is the correct answer.

Comment: @matt This does not help anyone solve anything. Thus, it is not an answer. I would like this error not to appear in my console. So far nothing I've done has helped. I normally run zero errors and zero warnings. This is a very frustrating situation.

Comment: @livingtech Of course it is. Apple dumps a _lot_ of unnecessary warnings into the console. It mostly happens on the simulator. Everyone hates it, not just you. So if you don't like it, do what we do: complain to Apple. But the  answer does help: it tells you to ignore it, which is correct. Whether you like the truth when you hear it is irrelevant.

Comment: @matt Just because something is truth does not make it an answer to a question. I'll admit that the original question does have a bit of ambiguity around what "solve" means, but if you take it to mean "remove the error from the console", then this is definitely not an answer to the question.

Comment: @livingtech But if you _can't_ remove it from the console, then being told that fact _is_ the answer.

Comment: this answer is not acceptable as you are just saying to ignored it but my app is crashed at startup and i can't go inside my side in ios and it showing the same message